# Cannot Insert Current Date in Database using ("en-NZ") Localization

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, date

Cannot Insert Current date into database while using date datatype.
I am Using MS SQL Server As The backend.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-NZ"));
```

Works While Using **ShortDate** Format But Need The Date IN Specific Localization

Comment: The usual advice. Do not store date/time in a database as strings. Use the supplied datatype for dates/times available from your database. You can always format the Date/Time in whichever format or locale you prefer when you need to display them. In the database let these values to be stored as dates/times

Comment: Please tell us what is the datatype of your column in your Sql Server Table that should receive the _localized_ date.

Comment: The Data Type is "Date" Itself And The localized Date Format is "dd/mm/yyyy" i need the date to be inserted in this format for that reason i am using en-NZ localization values provided by C#

Comment: Well, the code above takes a Date+Time (DateTime.Now) and convert it to a string representation of that value formatted with the culture info of en-NZ. But this value is a string and you cannot store it in a Date column. Why don't you try to write DateTime.Today without any conversion to a string? I could be more helpful but I need to see the whole code that you use to store your data (from the connection opening to the execution of the command)

Comment: Sure @Steve But First Let Me Try Your Suggestion

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("InvoiceDate", DateTime.Today.Date);`

Code I'm Using For The Required Parameter.
The Data is being inserted but in **31-May-15** whereas i need it in **31-5-15** or **31-5-2015** but doesn't seem to work out

Comment: Please understand that, what you see on screen is how the tool used to display the date represent it on screen to you. A date has no format. Don't worry about how this tool show it. As a programmer you retrieve the date value from the database column, store it again in a DateTime variable and finally you format the date variable (converting it to a string) in any way you like. The result of the conversion (the string) is displayed by your program to your user. This is how it works

Comment: Ooh.. I was worried about the way it was showing it